# Datetime or Timestamp for a MySQL field?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

This one is a question I have asked myself several times, when creating Databases for PHP/MySQL web application.

In Mysql, what'd you recommend between **Datetime** and **Timestamp** and why?.

Comment: Even if you are changing the server time zone you can make use of timestamp.
Date may not For time zone conversion also Time stamp is easy

Comment: For MySQL it makes no difference unless you plan to use the DEFAUL NOW or the on update tag. When Selecting the data you can convert it to system timestamp with a single extra command from mysql or a simple POSIX from any programming. both timestamp and datetime have the same type of saving field.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer datetimes stored in the UTC timezone because it is not based on some arbitrary time period, is easier to read, and lends itself nicely to a variety of database date functions.

But I don't fuss over this... if I have to work on a project that uses timestamps, it doesn't bother me.